# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/ReferenceMap error with commons-collections-2.1

Tags: jsf, apache-commons-collection

My project used below mentions jars:
**commons-collections-2.1.jar
myfaces-api-1.1.3.jar
myfaces-impl-1.1.3.jar**
 and jsf version 1.1 but getting this error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/ReferenceMap

and **commons-collection** jar is available at runtime.

Comment: You should have a look at the dependency graph, as it could be possible, that you have multiple apache-commons.jar versions in it.

Comment: You should drop 15 year old libraries